# Один пользователь для всех баз mysql или для каждой базы отдельный пользователь?

Tags: mysql

На виртуальном сервере создаю mySQL-базы для каждого из нескольких сайтов. Встал вопрос - нужно ли создавать для каждой базы отдельного пользователя (как это реализовано почти у всех хостинг-провайдеров) или можно создать одного пользователя и назначить его для всех созданных баз MySQL всех сайтов?

Comment: если хочешь, чтобы на кривом сайте дропнули данные прямо со всех баз - создавай одного, конечно.

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже подумал именно о безопасности всех баз